# Creating a Console Menu with Box Characters

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I've built a menu, but I want to format it to look like this:

[image]

With the menu title within a box and the selection choices in a box.

I found the box characters from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

╔═╗
║ ║
╚═╝

I want to use the length property of strings to draw the horizontal box lines.

Comment: wow...is there some reason not to just create a GUI?

Comment: Sarcastic though it may be, TessellatingHeckler has an excellent point. You haven't actually asked a question. What is it you need help with, what have you tried, and where are you having trouble with your attempts?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old, but it seems to have a lot of traffic from like-minded individuals who want a better menu option than `System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription`. I was looking for something similar and found [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576015/powershell-menu-selection-like-grub-curses-etc) that inspired me to write a menu system that surrounds the choices with a box adapted to the longest choice length or menu title:

```
┌Choose an option┐
│first           │
│second option   │
│third           │
└────────────────┘
```

The script only works in Powershell console, not ISE. Using the arrow keys will highlight a selection in reverse video. Hitting enter will return it.

```
function Show-SimpleMenu ([array]$MenuOptions, [string]$Title ='Choose an option'){
    $maxLength = ($MenuOptions | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum #get longest string length
    If($maxLength -lt $Title.Length){$maxLength = $Title.Length}
    $highlighted = 0 
    $MenuTop = [Console]::CursorTop
    Do{
        [Console]::CursorTop = $MenuTop
        Write-Host "┌$($Title.PadRight($maxLength,'─'))┐" 
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $MenuOptions.Length;$i++) {
            Write-Host "│" -NoNewLine
            if ($i -eq $highlighted) {
                Write-Host "$(([string]$MenuOptions[$i]).PadRight($maxLength,' '))" -fore $host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor -back $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor -NoNewline
            } else {
                Write-Host "$(([string]$MenuOptions[$i]).PadRight($maxLength,' '))" -fore $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor -back $host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor -NoNewline
            }
            Write-Host "│"
        }
        Write-Host "└$('─' * ($maxLength))┘"
        $keycode = [Console]::ReadKey($true)
        If ($keyCode.Key -eq [ConsoleKey]::UpArrow -and $highlighted -gt 0 ) {$highlighted--}
        If ($keycode.Key -eq [ConsoleKey]::DownArrow -and $highlighted -lt $MenuOptions.Length - 1) {$highlighted++}
    }While($keyCode.Key -ne [ConsoleKey]::Enter -and $keycode.Key -ne [ConsoleKey]::Escape )
    If($keyCode.Key -eq [ConsoleKey]::Enter){ $MenuOptions[$highlighted] }
}

Show-SimpleMenu @('first','second option','third')
```

There is also a [multi-select version on GitHub](https://github.com/mossrich/PowershellRecipes/blob/master/AsciiMenu.ps1) that allows choosing multiple options with the space bar.

Answer (score 1):

To make a 50-character (for example) horizontal line, you could do it like this:

```
PS> "═" * 50
══════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer anything regarding length property.  But, it looks like the example screenshot might just be using single characters and Write-Host as such.

`Write-Host "╔══════════╗"
Write-Host "║ Box Menu ║"
Write-Host "╚══════════╝"`

Answer (score 1):

This somewhat do the trick

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Script functions
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function MakeTop
{
    $string = "╔═"
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width - 4; $i++)
    {
        $string = $string + "═"
    }
    $string = $string + "═╗"

    return $string
}
function MakeMiddel
{
    $string = "╠═"
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width - 4; $i++)
    {
        $string = $string + "═"
    }
    $string = $string + "═╣"

    return $string
}
function MakeButtom
{
    $string = "╚═"
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width - 4; $i++)
    {
        $string = $string + "═"
    }
    $string = $string + "═╝"

    return $string
}

function MakeSpaces
{
    $string = "║ "
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width - 4; $i++)
    {
        $string = $string + " "
    }
    $string = $string + " ║"
    return $string
}

function CenterText
{
    param($Message)

    $string = "║ "

    for($i = 0; $i -lt (([Math]::Max(0, $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width / 2) - [Math]::Max(0, $Message.Length / 2))) - 4; $i++)
    {
        $string = $string + " "
    }

    $string = $string + $Message

    for($i = 0; $i -lt ($Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width - ((([Math]::Max(0, $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width / 2) - [Math]::Max(0, $Message.Length / 2))) - 2 + $Message.Length)) - 2; $i++)
    {
        $string = $string + " "
    }

    $string = $string + " ║"
    return $string

}


$MakeTop = MakeTop
$MakeMiddel = MakeMiddel
$MakeButtom = MakeButtom
$MakeSpaces = MakeSpaces



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Run
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$MakeTop
CenterText "Changing TCP/IP Settings"

$MakeMiddel

$MakeSpaces
CenterText "1. Change Settings to DHCP"
CenterText "2. Change Settings to STATIC"
CenterText "3. Exit Program"
$MakeSpaces
$MakeButtom

$UserInput = Read-Host "Please make a selection [1-3]"


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Handle input
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if($UserInput -eq "1")
{
    Write-Host "Setting TCP/IP Settings to DHCP"
    Read-Host
}
elseif($UserInput -eq "2")
{
    Write-Host "Setting TCP/IP Settings to STATIC"
    Read-Host
}
```

And give the output

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                               Changing TCP/IP Settings                                   ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║                                                                                          ║
║                              1. Change Settings to DHCP                                  ║
║                             2. Change Settings to STATIC                                 ║
║                                   3. Exit Program                                        ║
║                                                                                          ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
Please make a selection [1-3]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mikki! You got me going with your script. Here I have modified it a bit mostly for color.

```
# Created By Mikki Sørensen 11-15-2019 @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773684/creating-a-console-menu-with-box-characters
# Heavily modified by Fried Synapse 11-02-2023
#############################################################################################################
# Functions
function MkTop {
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $BoxWidth; $i++){
        $string = $string + "═"
    }
    write-host "╔═" -Fore $BoxFgColor -nonewline -Back $BoxBgColor
    write-host $string -Fore $BoxFgColor -nonewline -Back $BoxBgColor
    write-host "═╗" -Fore $BoxFgColor -Back $BoxBgColor
}

function MkLn {
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $BoxWidth; $i++) {
        $string = $string + "═"
    }
    write-host "╠═" -Fore $BoxFgColor -nonewline -Back $BoxBgColor
    write-host $string -Fore $BoxFgColor -nonewline -Back $BoxBgColor
    write-host "═╣" -Fore $BoxFgColor -Back $BoxBgColor
}

function MkBtm {    
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $BoxWidth; $i++) {
        $string = $string + "═"
    }
    write-host "╚═" -Fore $BoxFgColor -nonewline -Back $BoxBgColor
    write-host $string -Fore $BoxFgColor -nonewline -Back $BoxBgColor
    write-host "═╝" -Fore $BoxFgColor -Back $BoxBgColor
}

function MkBlank {    
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $BoxWidth; $i++){
        $string = $string + " "
    }
    write-host "║ " -Fore $BoxFgColor -Back $BoxBgColor -nonewline
    write-host $string -nonewline -Back $BoxBgColor
    write-host " ║" -Fore $BoxFgColor -Back $BoxBgColor
}

function CntrT {
    param($Fcolor, $Txt)
    for($i = 0; $i -lt ($BoxWidth - $Txt.length) /2 ; $i++) {
        $string = $string + " "
    }
    
    $string = $string + $Txt    
    for($i = $i; $i -lt ($BoxWidth - $Txt.length +1); $i++) {    
        $string = $string + " "
    }
    
    write-host "║ " -Fore $BoxFgColor -Back $BoxBgColor -nonewline
    write-host $string -Fore $Fcolor -Back $BoxBgColor -nonewline
    write-host "║" -Fore $BoxFgColor -Back $BoxBgColor 
}

function LeftT {
param($LocX, $Fcolor, $Txt)    
    for($i = 0; $i -lt ($locx); $i++) {
        $string = $string + " "
    }
        
    $string = $string + $Txt    
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt (($BoxWidth - $Txt.length)-$locx+1); $i++) {
        $string = $string + " "
    }
    write-host "║ " -Fore $BoxFgColor  -Back $BoxBgColor -nonewline
    write-host $string -Fore $Fcolor -Back $BoxBgColor -nonewline
    write-host "║" -Fore $BoxFgColor -Back $BoxBgColor
}

#############################################################################################################
# MAIN
# Color choices a

    re Black DarkBlue DarkGreen DarkCyan DarkRed DarkMagenta DarkYellow Gray DarkGray Blue Green Cyan Red Magenta Yellow White
    
    #Box description Parameters: Width of the box, Foreground color, Background color
    $BoxWidth = 80
    $BoxFgColor = "White"
    $BoxBgColor = "red"
    
    clear-host
    
    #Create the box and items by calling desired funtions
    MkTop
    CntrT Green "Menu Title"
    
    MkLn
    
    MkBlank #Meaning no text, just background
    CntrT Magenta "1. Option 1 jhlkhlk" #Center the text in the box
    CntrT Blue    "1. Option 1 jhlkhl"
    CntrT Cyan    "3. Option3"
    LeftT  20 Yellow  "4. Option4" #Left justify the text at your specified start point
    LeftT  20 Green   "5. Exit"
    MkBlank
    MkBtm #Create the bottom line
    
    #Ask the user for thir Choice
    Write-Host "Please make a choice (1-5) :" -NoNewline
    $UsrChoice = Read

-Host

#############################################################################################################
# Decision Process
switch ($UsrChoice) {
    "1" {"Change settings"; break}
    "2" {"Static settings"; break}
    "3" {"option 3"; break}
    "4" {"Near the end"; break}
    default {"Please choose only from the displayed list"; break}
}
```

Here is the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5HOa.png)