# PowerShell IntelliSense on parameters

Tags: function, powershell, intellisense

If I type `Get-Help ena` I can then do `Tab` or `Ctrl-Space` to show the available commands (I'm calling that IntelliSense, is there another more correct PowerShell term for this?).

I am writing a function and it has one parameter which I want to also be subject to `Tab` and `Ctrl-Space` and ideally I would like this parameter to have IntelliSense tab completion (and `Ctrl-Space`) for Cmdlets and Module names and Aliases. Does someone know how to activate that functionality for a function parameter?

Comment: This was exactly the topic for the IDERA PowerShell Tips of the Day for the past week or so (12 Mar 2020 to 17 Mar 2020) - you can see them all at [the IDERA PowerTips Blog](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/).

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118870/45375) to the linked duplicate solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Zeitlin. wow. pretty amazing timing for me asking this question (it had been on my mind for about 6 weeks but I didn't get around to asking). Thanks also @mklement0 for this, two great links for me to get information from, I'll spend some time looking at both.`ArgumentCompleter` looks ideal.